# Use entity manager in SQLFilter

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am creating a filter that extends SQLFilter as in https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/filters.html, I would like to know how to get and use Entity Manager in a filter. SQLFilter class has already an $em value :

```
abstract class SQLFilter
{
    /**
     * The entity manager.
     *
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;
```

But it's private. Is there a way to get the Entity Manager ? Maybe it's a bad practice to use an entity manager in a SQLFilter ?

Comment: Indeed, attempt to use a private field might be a sign for something you shouldn't do ... whats the goal you want to reach? Maybe it's better to create an intermediate class which gets an sql filter and the separate entity manager as dependency injection?

Comment: I have an User entity, this user can have multiple objects, I am currently filtering requests on objects based on user if there is one on request. I would like that, if the user has no objects, default behaviour would be that the user has access to all objects. In order to do that, I think I need to check in my filter if the user has objects, and to put no filter if that is not the case. I could do this verification in every controller, but I would be losing the advantage to have one global filter.